# Launching a cloned EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

For the option to launch a new EC2 instance like this one, how similar is the instance? Does it include all cron jobs, or what exactly is contained in the new instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will create a new instance using the same AMI, Availability Zone, and Security groups. (Note that if the AMI no longer exists, this will not be possible.)

If you're worried about 2 instances running the same cron jobs, I would suggest disabling the cron process in the AMI, then edit them to run after the instance is created. If it's too late and the cron jobs are already in the original AMI, you'll probably want to spawn the new one at a time between when the jobs run so you have enough time to log into the 2nd machine and turn them off before they run again.